# Allowing user to customize the items on the list menubar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've created a simple menu bar

using bootstrap. now i want the user to be able to edit the items on the list including the links on the menu, add, delete etc. How do i do this using just frontend code like javascript etc?

Code:

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-menu">
     <a>MENU</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
     <a href="#" target="myframe">Link #1</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
     <a href="#">Link #2</a>
    </li>

    <li>
     <a href="#">Link #3</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
     <a href="#">Link #4</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: There's not enough information about exactly what you're trying to do and the details of implementation. Is the user any person who visits the site in a web browser or is it someone like a client updating the content of their website? Also when you say "add, delete, etc." I'm not sure what the "etc." means. If the changes to the menu need to be permanent, you'll probably need to use some kind of database to store the data. Can you give some more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I mean no the changes don't need to be permanent for now, I am aware that that would require using a database but I just mean any person using the site

Comment: and I just mean being able to edit the text or add to or delete from menu on the user end that's it

Comment: You've still left out a lot of pertinent details. What does a user have to do to be able to edit these menu items? Do they click an "edit" button that takes them into some kind of edit mode, make changes and then press "submit?" Are there buttons next to each menu item that allow for editing at any time? There just are not enough details here to help you.

Comment: yes sounds about right. you got the gist of it. an edit button that allows for any changes in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is possible with vanilla Javascript, jQuery, or a host of other libraries. jQuery is where I'd recommend you start.

You can create new elements by passing html elements as strings to the jQuery function. See the "Creating New Elements" section of [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). Using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) as Muzammil mentioned, you can add and remove elements from the DOM.

I've created a [small jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hendeca/ow2p6gru/3/) demonstrating some of the functions I'm talking about and how you might use them. This is a limited demo that doesn't include every feature you'd want for a full implementation, but uses some of the pertinent jQuery functions.

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-menu">
     <a>MENU</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
     <a href="#" target="myframe">Link #1</a>
     <button class="delete-link">Delete</button>
    </li> 

    <li>
     <a href="#">Link #2</a>
     <button class="delete-link">Delete</button>
    </li>

    <li>
     <a href="#">Link #3</a>
     <button class="delete-link">Delete</button>
    </li> 

    <li>
     <a href="#">Link #4</a>
     <button class="delete-link">Delete</button>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <div class="input-field">
     <label for="link-title">Enter link title</label>
     <input type="text" class="link-title" name="link-title" placeholder="link Title" />
   </div>

   <div class="input-field">
     <label for="link-title">Enter link URL</label>
     <input type="url" class="link-url" name="link-url" />
   </div>

   <input type="submit" class="add-button" value="Add" />
 </div>
```

Javascript w/ jQuery

```
var $addButton = $('.add-button');
var $sidebarMenu = $('.sidebar-nav');

// Add the event handlers
$(document).on('click', '.delete-link', removeLink);
$addButton.on('click', addLink);

function removeLink(e) {
    // Remove the parent <li> element of the clicked link
    var $link = $(e.currentTarget).closest('li');
  $link.remove();
}

function addLink(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $linkTitle = $('.link-title');
  var $linkUrl = $('.link-url');
  // Create the new link element using values from text inputs
  var $link = $('<li>').append(
    $('<a>').attr('href', $linkUrl.val()).text($linkTitle.val()));

  // Add a delete button for the link
  $link.append($('<button>').addClass('delete-link').text('Delete'));
  $sidebarMenu.append($link);
  // Reset the text inputs
  $linkTitle.val('');
  $linkUrl.val('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to achieve this, the following function will help you : [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)